# How to set CSS properties on a Konva Stage?

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, konvajs

I just started using Konva, so I'm still learning how it works. I'd like to be able to dymanically set some CSS properties on the Canvas element that Konva creates as the "stage". For a simple example, let's say I want to add a border. What I've seen online so far looks like this:

```
        const stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 340,
            height: 300
        });

        stage.getContainer().style.border = '1px solid black';
```

This isn't working however, as it seems that "**getContainer()**" is no longer available. (At least, VS Code is giving me an error). I am assuming this is deprecated code.

I can always add a Rectangle and draw the border there, but the border is not really the question here and the rectangle is a work-around. There must be some way to add CSS directly to the canvas? As an aside, I need this to be dynamic. For example, if I wanted the border, I could just create a normal CSS rule and match it to the canvas selector, but that still doesn't work for me. Let's say tI need to change the color, thickness and type of border each time. I need to create the CSS dynamically and attach it to the canvas.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: What error do you have? You sample code works just fine: http://jsbin.com/mequboqifo/edit?js,output

Comment: Wrap the canvas container element in another element and set the styling on that outer element? Also, just re the 'add a bounding rectangle as the border' approach - this thickness of this 'border' will grow as you zoom the canvas meaning that without revertnig to more complexity it is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stage.getContent()` to get the outer most DIV of the konva stage.